# error during token replacement in macros

Tags: macros

I wrote this small program expecting that the values will be placed and it would see the output but i get an error:

D:\C Programming\token-pasting.c||In function 'main':|
D:\C Programming\token-pasting.c|6|error: 'Hell23' undeclared (first use in this function)|
D:\C Programming\token-pasting.c|6|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  swap(front, back)  front##back

main()
{
swap(Hell, 23) ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really don't know how the error message could be clearer: your macro turns (Hell, 23) into Hell23, which isn't defined. 

`##` concatenates, by the way. swap's a weird name for that macro

Comment: @Ben please explain what should be the code to fix the errror? I have just started of with this topic and its lil weird

Comment: You haven't explained what it is you're trying to do

Comment: @Ben i Want to print hell123 however i haven't used printf command here even if i do...i get this error. What is this error showing you haven't used the function

Comment: printf is very well documented. You'd be better served looking it up instead of having me guess what it is you want. Is it `printf("hell123");` ?

Comment: @Ben printf(swap(hell,21));

Comment: and get a output hell21 on screen

Answer (score 0):

There's a million ways to print "hell21", still need context. And ditch your "swap" macro...

```
char *str = "hell";
int x = 21;
printf("%s%d", str, x);
```

`%s` says to replace that part of printf with a string array, `%d` says to replace that part of printf with an integer.

Comment: i know there are other method but this is given the K&R book so what's the purpose of giving this?

Comment: It's simpler to change or replace a variable than it is to reformat a printf.